# Find largest element from multidimensional array of ints

Tags: ruby

I have an array of ints similar to this:

```
 values = [[3, 4, 15, 16, 5, 13, 2], [1, 12, 13, 2, 10, -1], [11, 12, 1, 9, -2], [1, -10, -2, -13], [-11, -3, -14], [8, -3], [-11]]
```

How would I retrieve the index of the largest number, e.g. `16 == values[0][3]`?

Comment: `values.flat_map { |x| x }.max`

Comment: What have you tried because this is fairly trivial e.g. `values.flatten.max`

Comment: I need to know the location of the highest number, e.g. if it is the first value in the 4th array, then `values[3][0]`. The indexes are what I'm after, less so the value itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't sure I get you correct, but anyway:

1) If you need the largest element:

```
values.flatten.max
```

2) If you need largest element from each subarray:

```
values.map{|x| x.max}
```

**UPD**

About indexes:

```
largest_element = values.flatten.max
values.each_with_index do |e,i|
  if e.include?(largest_element)
    p i
    values[i].each_with_index{|e, i| p i if e == largest_el}
  end
end
```

Comment: +1 just to support the right answer but I don't believe this question is even valid due to the trivial nature of the procedure requested.

Comment: I just modified the question. Messed up the wording.